# How do I execute a function by a T value in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a Router class that extends a Dictionary-like class. I want the invoke function of the Router class to treate a value in the key-value pair as a function. I'm new to Typescript and getting type errors. Not sure how to cast it as a function without having to change the Dictionary Object.

**Router**

```
export class Routes<T> extends Dictionary<T> {

    invoke(key:string = window.location.hash):void {
        [super.get(key):string]();
    }

}
```

**Dictionary**

```
export class Dictionary<T> {

    private _items: { [key: string]: T };

    constructor(items:{ [key: string]: T } = {}) {
        this._items = items;
    }

    add(key: string, value: T): void {
        this._items[key] = value;
    }

    get(key: string): T {
        return this._items[key];
    }

    remove(key: string): void {
        delete this._items[key];
    }

    contains(key: string): boolean {
        return key in this._items;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your router holds function then you better do:

```
export class Routes extends Dictionary<Function> {
    invoke(key: string = window.location.hash): void {
        this.get(key)();
    }
}
```

But I think that this might be better:

```
interface RouterHandler {
    (): void;
}

export class Routes extends Dictionary<RouterHandler> {
    invoke(key: string = window.location.hash): void {
        this.get(key)();
    }
}
```

This way you can control the signature of your callbacks, even have different ones (by extending this interface with another).

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This should suffice, assuming the previous definition of Dictionary

```
export class Routes<T extends Function> extends Dictionary<T> {
    invoke(key:string = window.location.hash):void {
        super.get(key)();
    }
}
```

Separate File

```
import {Route} from './<route-file>';
type FunctionType = ()=>string
let r = new Routes<FunctionType>()
r.invoke("key")
```

And of note the FunctionType can be any input type to any output type depending on your needs.  If it is a void function then function type could be expressed as:

```
type FunctionType = ()=>void
```